# Проблема при считывании новостных лент file_get_contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

Есть две новостные ленты:

1. "http://inosmi.ru/export/rss2/index.xml". 
   Ее содержимое:
   `"
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" version="2.0"><channel>title>ИноСМИ - Все, что достойно
    перевода</title>
        ... "`
2. "http://www.kommersant.ru/RSS/main.xml"
   Ее содержимое:

   `" <?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?> <rss version="2.0">
        <channel>
            <language>ru</language>
            <copyright>1991-2019, АО &quot;Коммерсантъ&quot;</copyright> ...
   "`

РАНЬШЕ СЧИТЫВАЛИСЬ ОБЕ. Сейчас  первая "inosmi.ru " не считывается.
У меня под подозрением фрагмент 
`"<rss xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" ..."`

Пробовал читать так:

```
    $temp = file_put_contents('../log.txt', file_get_contents(urlencode("http://inosmi.ru/export/rss2/index.xml")));
```

И так пробовал:

```
    libxml_use_internal_errors(true);    
    $rss = simplexml_load_file("http://inosmi.ru/export/rss2/index.xml");
    $fp = fopen('../log2.txt', 'w');
    if ($rss === false) {
        $err = "Ошибка загрузки XML\n";
        foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
            $err = $err. "\t". $error->message;
        }
    fwrite($fp, $err );
    }
    fclose($fp);
```

В log.txt пишет

```
> "Ошибка загрузки XML  failed to load external entity
> "http://inosmi.ru/export/rss2/index.xml""
```

Comment: У меня вот так `simplexml_load_file("http://inosmi.ru/export/rss2/index.xml"); ` все считывается.

Comment: так... а у меня почему "failed to load external entity" ? При этом мозила открывает.

Comment: ВЫЛОЖИЛ свой сайт на хостинг. ТАМ ВСЕ РАБОТАЕТ!!!!
Подскажите, пожалуйста, видно у меня что-то с настройками или версия PHP не та.
У меня стоит денвер Denwer3_Base_2013-06-02_a2.2.22_p5.3.13_m5.5.25_pma3.5.1_xdebug.exe
Может XML-файл очень большой? Есть в настройках ограничение по длине?